# Add some action in SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

I need that the variable inside selectItems be available inside selectOneMenu or other way that I can grab what were selected by the user.

I need this because this item need to pass trough an Hibernate.initialize(item)

So I need to call the view (bean) method that I have build that does it.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu
    id="dependenteSalvar"
    value="#{pessoaView.registro}"
    styleClass="form-control"
    converter="indexConverter">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Selecione..."></f:selectItem>
    <t:selectItems
        value="#{pessoaView.pessoasAtivas}"
        var="dependente"
        itemLabel="#{dependente.nome} (#{dependente.documento})"
        itemValue="#{dependente}">
   </t:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu >
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <f:ajax> tag to listen the events of selectOneMenu in your backend.

```
 <h:selectOneMenu
    id="dependenteSalvar"
    value="#{pessoaView.registro}"
    styleClass="form-control"
    converter="indexConverter">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Selecione..."></f:selectItem>
    <t:selectItems
        value="#{pessoaView.pessoasAtivas}"
        var="dependente"
        itemLabel="#{dependente.nome} (#{dependente.documento})"
        itemValue="#{dependente}">
   </t:selectItems>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" />

</h:selectOneMenu >
```

Take into account that <f:ajax> requires jsf.js file is included in the HTML <h:head>. Basically, this file contains the Javascript functions to perform the magic.

Another option if you are using primefaces is to use
<p:ajax event="change" listener... /> instead of f:ajax, to listen the value change events as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
    id="dependenteSalvar"
    value="#{pessoaView.registro}"
    styleClass="form-control">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Selecione..."></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{pessoaView.pessoasAtivas}"
        var="dependente"
        itemLabel="#{dependente.nome} (#{dependente.documento})"
        itemValue="#{dependente}">
   </f:selectItems>
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" event="change" />

</p:selectOneMenu >
```